# The rendering method does not work inside the root

Tags: react-router-dom

The rendering method does not work inside the root in react router dom
and only the element works

```
return (
 <Routes>
    <Route
        path="/"
        exact
        render={() => <Course courses={Courses} />}/> //dose not work
       <Route path="/Login" exact element={<Login />} /> //its work
</Routes>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` component API changed significantly. There is no longer any `component` and `render` and `children` function props, they were replaced by the single `element` prop that takes a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, value.

[Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

In other words, there is no `render` prop that takes a function.

Notice there is also no longer an `exact` prop as routes are now *always* exactly matched in RRDv6. The reason the `render` function prop existed in RRDv5 was to allow props to be passed to the routed component. Since routed components are rendered as JSX in RRDv6 props can be directly passed.

```
return (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Course courses={Courses} />} />
    <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
  </Routes>
);
```